# Absolutely positioning footer in scrollable div

Tags: html, css, scroll, footer, sticky

I can not seem to make a footer stick to the bottom of a scrollable div.
The footer should stick to the bottom when the div has few characters or many characters and overflows. Also note this is NOT on the body but any arbitrary div.

```
  <div class="blue">
        <div class="red">
          Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet Nam liber tempor cum
          soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim soluta nobis eleifend option congue
          nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim
          placerat facer possim Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim
        </div>

      <div class="lime">footer</div>
</div>

<style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
      height: 90%
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .blue {
      position: relative;
      border: solid 5px blue;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .red {
      width: 200px;
      border: solid 5px red;
      margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .lime {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      width: 250px;
      height: 100px;
      border: solid 5px lime;
    }
</style>
```

here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CaptM44/yk99pgzz/

UPDATE:
[this image shows the requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yh4V.png)

notice the content length, and the scrollbar positions

Comment: I need a little clarification: "The footer should stick to the bottom"The bottom of what? The blue div, the red div, or the bottom of the screen? 

" when the div has few characters or many characters and overflows."  When which div has a few characters or many characters?

Comment: I added an image with the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a particular combination of `min-height`, `max-height` and `justify-content`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.blue {
  border: solid 5px blue;
  max-height: 90vh;
  min-height: 90vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.red {
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 5px red;
}

.lime {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 5px lime;
  width: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
    <div class="red">
      Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet Nam liber tempor cum
      soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim soluta nobis eleifend option congue
      nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim
      placerat facer possim Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim
    </div>

  <div class="lime">footer</div>
</div>
```

Note you need to set both `min-height` and `max-height` on `.blue` for this to work. Replace `90vh` with your desired container height.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. I added an image with the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your lime relative, and just give negative margin that equals to its height:

```
.lime {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -100px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 5px lime;
}
```

also remove margin from red:

```
.red {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 5px red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. I added an image with the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "wrapper" element to wrap `.red` inside of it. For `.wrapper` you set 100% height and `overflow-y` and `.lime` will go "after" `.wrapper`.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qx1L6974/)

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. I added an image with the requirements.